# Let $n=am+r$ with $m \ge a>5$ and $r \ge 0$. Prove that $\phi(n) \ge m$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics, conjectures

I understand that for all $n>6$, we have $\phi(n) \ \ge  \ \sqrt n $. This fact however is not getting me anywhere towards the proof of the claim in question.
($a, m, r$ are all integers)

Comment: It appears all counterexamples occur when $a \ | \ r$. Suppose we add an extra condition $a \ \nmid \ r$, can this be proven? Can anyone cite another counterexample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is false (for $a>4$ as in the original post, but also for $a>5$ with a different example). Take for example $a=5$ and $m=6006$, $r=0$. Then
$$
\phi(30030)=\phi(5\cdot 6006)=\phi(5)\cdot \phi(6006)=4\cdot 1440=5760,
$$
which is not bigger or equal to $m=6006$. In fact, we have
$$
\lim \inf \frac{\phi(n)}{n}=0.
$$

Comment: I hadn't noticed that. It appears if I made a slight tightening of  the inequality $a>4$ to $a>5$, the claim may be true. I have edited the question. Could you provide some counterexamples with this addition?

Comment: As I said, you can always make counterexamples, because of  $$
\lim \inf \frac{\phi(n)}{n}=0.
$$ For $a=6$ just look for the first $n$ such that $\phi(n)/n<\frac{1}{6}$.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that. There are actually infinitely many counterexamples! My initial investigation was limited to the case when $r=1$. I thought generalising this would work for $r \ge 0$ but as you have shown it hasn't. From further results, it appears all the counterexamples occur when $a \ | \ r$. Suppose we added an extra condition $a \nmid r$, does your illustration of finding at least one such $n$ still hold? For $a=5$, $r=1$, there's no such $n$ with $n \le 10^{8}$

Comment: let me know of your findings so I can decide whether to write a new question with the additional condition $ a \ \nmid \ r$.

Comment: I think it doesn't matter. However, the counterexamples then will be very large, and it will be impossible to compute them explicitly. Only an existence result then can be given.

Comment: With $a=5$ and $r=0$,  $m<10^7$, I found 7793 values of $m$ such that $n=am+r$ is a counterexample and yet with the same bound of $m$ I find no counterexamples when $a=4$ and $ r =1$. Why is that? I still believe there may be no counterexamples in this particular example or in general when $a \ \nmid \ r$.